# Sum of fractions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fractions

Let $a_1 < a_2 <a_3 < a_4$ be positive integers such that $\sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac {1}{ a_i}$=$ 11/6$. Then $a_4-a_2=?$

I've tried to find the $a_i$'s but couldn't.

Is there a general way to solve such equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $2\leq a_1<a_2<a_3<a_4$ then 
$$\frac{77}{60}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\geq \sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac {1}{ a_i}=\frac{11}{6}$$
which is a contradiction. Hence $a_1=1$.

Now we are left with $2\leq a_2<a_3<a_4$ such that
$$\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}+\frac{1}{a_4}=\frac{5}{6}.$$

Similarly if $3\leq a_2<a_3<a_4$ then
$$\frac{47}{60}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\geq \frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}+\frac{1}{a_4}=\frac{5}{6}.$$
which is a contradiction. Hence $a_2=2$.

Then we have to solve
$$\frac{1}{a_3}+\frac{1}{a_4}=\frac{1}{3}$$
with $3\leq a_3<a_4$. With $a_3=3$ and $a_3\geq 6$ we have again a contradiction, so $a_3$ can be $4$ or $5$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'd reached till here. Then I found that the values of $a_i$, i.e., they can be 3,4,4. But the condition provided is that the following number strictly greater than the preceding number. There can be other combinations too, like 6,6,2 but one of the a's would be repeating.

Comment: @Rhea What is $a_2$? Note that $1/3+1/4+1/5<5/6$.

Comment: $a_2$ can be 3, $a_3$=4, $a_4$=4.Also $1/2+1/4+1/3$>$1$

Comment: I thought so, it was asked in an exam.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help.